# jquery closest selector in text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$(".class1").children(".class2") <=> ".class1 > .class2"
$(".class1").find(".class2") <=> ".class1 .class2"
$(".class1").closest(".class2") <=> ?
```

Does something like ".class1:closest(.class2)" exist?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the third line of your code block does already?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

What David said.

Comment: There is no css2/css3 parent selector nor a jQuery selector. You have to go with `.closest()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.closest` goes up the DOM tree, while `.children` and `.find` go down it. No, there is no shorthand way to write it as a selector.